# Pandas Multi-index Merge with Multiple Nodes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have three network nodes. Each with a dataframe. Within these dataframe, one of them has two IDs. The other two has one for each. Example such as the following:

df (node0):

```
| id1 | id2 | col1| col2|
| :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
| 1   | A   |  h  |  i  |
| 2   | B   |  j  |  k  |
| 3   | C   |  l  |  r  |
| 4   | D   |  v  |  d  |
| 5   | E   |  x  |  y  |
| 6   | F   |  w  |  p  |
```

df1 (node1):

```
| id1 | col3| col4|
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| 1   | k   |  h  |
| 2   | d   |  j  |
| 3   | e   |  l  |
```

df2 (node2):

```
| id2 | col5| col6|
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| B   | k   |  h  |
| C   | d   |  j  |
| D   | d   |  j  |
| E   | e   |  l  |
```

*Note that all *col* values does not matter, it can be anything. Only focuses on IDs

Now, I want to merge these three dataframe in a way that:

1. Intersect df with df1 and df2 with there respective ID. i.e. df: id1 - df1: id1, df: id2 - df2: id2
2. **Depend on the input**, Intersect or Union results from step 1. to produce final results for **EACH NODES**. Which in this case:

**INTERSECT**:

node0:

```
| id1 | id2 | col1| col2|
| :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
| 2   | B   |  j  |  k  |
| 3   | C   |  l  |  r  |
```

node1:

```
| id1 | col3| col4|
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| 2   | d   |  j  |
| 3   | e   |  l  |
```

node2:

```
| id2 | col5| col6|
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| B   | k   |  h  |
| C   | d   |  j  |
```

**UNION**

node0:

```
| id1 | id2 | col1| col2|
| :-: | :-: | :-: | :-: |
| 1   | A   |  h  |  i  |
| 2   | B   |  j  |  k  |
| 3   | C   |  l  |  r  |
| 4   | D   |  v  |  d  |
| 5   | E   |  x  |  y  |
```

node1:

```
| id1 | col3| col4|
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| 1   | k   |  h  |
| 2   | d   |  j  |
| 3   | e   |  l  |
| 4   |     |     |
| 5   |     |     |
```

node2:

```
| id2 | col5| col6|
| :-: | :-: | :-: |
| A   |     |     |
| B   | k   |  h  |
| C   | d   |  j  |
| D   | d   |  j  |
| E   | e   |  l  |
```

Now, results for UNION might seems strange. But remember you **ALWAYS** intersect base df with other two first. Then intersect or union the results later.

Finally, filling **None** in the union for these IDs are expending but not in original respective dataframe.

There can be cases where base df(node0) has less ids than df1 or df2. In which idea is the same, you filling None in base df.

Important note: **three outputs always have SAME ROWS no matter intersect or union, but can be different columns. And the order can not be broken.**

I tryed several ways with no fruits. Sometimes the order is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example code:

```
import pandas as pd

# INTERSECT or UNION 
inputs = "UNION"
if inputs == "INTERSECT":
    merge_method = 'inner'
elif inputs == "UNION":
    merge_method = 'outer'
else:
    raise ValueError("inputs must be \"INTERSECT\" or \"UNION\" ")

d = {'id1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
      'id2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'],
      'col1': ['h', 'j', 'l', 'v', 'x', 'w'],
      'col2': ['i', 'k', 'r', 'd', 'y', 'p']}

'''
# Case where df has less ids than df1 or df2
d = {'id1': [1, 2], 
      'id2': ['A', 'B'],
      'col1': ['h', 'j'],
      'col2': ['i', 'k']}
'''

d1 = {'id1': [1, 2, 3],
      'col3': ['k', 'd', 'e'],
      'col4': ['h', 'j', 'l']}

d2 = {'id2': ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
      'col5': ['k', 'd', 'd', 'e'],
      'col6': ['h', 'j', 'j', 'l']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(d2)
# Expend base df if it has less ids than df1 or df2
df0 = pd.merge(df, df1, how='outer', on='id1')[df.columns.tolist()]
df0 = pd.merge(df0, df2, how='outer', on='id2')[df.columns.tolist()]

# Intersect df with df1 and df2 with there respective ID. i.e. df: id1 - df1: id1, df: id2 - df2: id2
int_df1 = pd.merge(df0, df1, how='inner', on='id1')[['id1', 'id2']]
int_df2 = pd.merge(df0, df2, how='inner', on='id2')[['id1', 'id2']]
print("df and df1 intersection: \n{}\ndf and df2 intersection: \n{}\n".format(int_df1, int_df2))

# Depend on the input, Intersect or Union results from step 1. to produce final results for EACH NODES
merge_df = pd.merge(int_df1, int_df2, how=merge_method, on=['id1', 'id2'])
df_out = pd.merge(merge_df, df0, how='inner', on=['id1', 'id2'])
df1_out = pd.merge(merge_df['id1'], df1, how=merge_method, on='id1')
df2_out = pd.merge(merge_df['id2'], df2, how=merge_method, on='id2')

# Filling None in the union for these IDs are expending but not in original respective dataframe
mask = (~df_out['id1'].isin(df['id1'])) | (~df_out['id2'].isin(df['id2']))
df_out.loc[mask] = df_out.loc[mask].fillna("None")

mask = ~df1_out['id1'].isin(df1['id1'])
df1_out.loc[mask] = df1_out.loc[mask].fillna("None")

mask = ~df2_out['id2'].isin(df2['id2'])
df2_out.loc[mask] = df2_out.loc[mask].fillna("None")
print("merge_df: \n{}\nnode0: \n{}\nnode1: \n{}\nnode2: \n{}\n".format(merge_df, df_out, df1_out, df2_out))
```

Outputs for **INTERSECT**:

```
df and df1 intersection: 
   id1 id2
0    1   A
1    2   B
2    3   C
df and df2 intersection:
   id1 id2
0    2   B
1    3   C
2    4   D
3    5   E

merge_df: 
   id1 id2
0    2   B
1    3   C
node0:
   id1 id2 col1 col2
0    2   B    j    k
1    3   C    l    r
node1:
   id1 col3 col4
0    2    d    j
1    3    e    l
node2:
  id2 col5 col6
0   B    k    h
1   C    d    j
```

Outputs for **UNION**:

```
df and df1 intersection: 
   id1 id2
0    1   A
1    2   B
2    3   C
df and df2 intersection:
   id1 id2
0    2   B
1    3   C
2    4   D
3    5   E

merge_df: 
   id1 id2
0    1   A
1    2   B
2    3   C
3    4   D
4    5   E
node0:
   id1 id2 col1 col2
0    1   A    h    i
1    2   B    j    k
2    3   C    l    r
3    4   D    v    d
4    5   E    x    y
node1:
   id1  col3  col4
0    1     k     h
1    2     d     j
2    3     e     l
3    4  None  None
4    5  None  None
node2:
  id2  col5  col6
0   A  None  None
1   B     k     h
2   C     d     j
3   D     d     j
4   E     e     l
```

Comment: This is great. I figured out eventually by myself. I created a new index for tracking order then sort them in the final step. But I thinks yours is more elegant. This is just the start for a much more complicated merge algorithm. Which has potentially duplicated IDs, multiple id matching, time selection. But thanks a lot for this answer.  Cheers!

Comment: @YehuiHe Glad to help. Cheers : )